# how to keep hairs black without using hair color?

Tags: hair

i am losing my natural hair color as time passes, my hair turns grey that is not such a good change. i am just 21 years old and feels too much worried about this premature graying of my hair.Please suggest me how i keep my hairs black without using hair color?

Comment: I think it may be better to seek help with the negative mental associations you have over grey hair than to try and resist what is for your body simply a part of its natural aging process

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a health issue.